# loading modules and factories files using angular ui routing and ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

i', using angular ui routing with ocLazyLoad to load the appendices files according to the choosen stat as the following code shows

my problem is:

**when i load a new state and click refresh sometime the factories is not initialized** -i think it's because the files is not fully loaded before init the controller-

i also tried to merge all files in the same ocLazyLoad function and use `serie : true` but dosenot work

is it the right use of ocLazyLoad

i've the following modules

```
  angular.module('app', [ "oc.lazyLoad"]);
  angular.module("app.inventory", []);
  angular.module("app.sales", []);
```

and here is the routing

```
.state("invoicesAddEdit", {
          url: "/invoice/:invoiceId",
          templateUrl: "app/components/sales/invoice/views/invoiceAddEdit.view.html",
          controller: "InvoiceAddEditController",

          resolve: {
              invoiceId: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
                  return $stateParams.invoiceId;
              }],
              settings: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      name: "app.settings",
                      files: [
                              "app/components/settings/settings.module.js",
                              "app/components/settings/currency/services/currency.factory.js",
                              "app/components/settings/deliveryMan/services/deliveryMan.factory.js",

                      ]
                  })
              }],

              inventory: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      name: "app.inventory",
                      files: [
                              "app/components/inventory/inventory.module.js",
                              "app/components/inventory/customer/services/customer.factory.js",
                              "app/components/inventory/store/services/store.factory.js",
                              "app/components/inventory/product/services/product.factory.js",

                      ]
                  })
              }],
              purchasing: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      name: "app.purchasing",
                      files: [
                              "app/components/purchasing/purchasing.module.js",
                              "app/components/purchasing/purchaseOrder/services/purchaseOrder.factory.js",

                      ]
                  })
              }],
              sales: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      name: "app.sales",
                      files: [
                              "app/components/sales/sales.module.js",
                              "app/components/sales/representative/services/representative.factory.js",

                              "app/components/sales/invoice/services/invoice.factory.js",
                              "app/components/sales/invoice/controllers/invoiceAddEdit.controller.js",

                      ]
                  })
              }],
          }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject the oCLazy Load as deps and insert the required files before specific tag in the html like the following :

```
      resolve: {
          invoiceId: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
              return $stateParams.invoiceId;
          }],
          deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                 name: "app.settings",
                 insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', 
                 files: [
                          "app/components/settings/settings.module.js",
                          "app/components/settings/currency/services/currency.factory.js",
                          "app/components/settings/deliveryMan/services/deliveryMan.factory.js",

                  ]
              })
          }],
```

Add the following link to the header of the html page or the View:

```
  <link id="ng_load_plugins_before"/>
```